# I want to run my two server like IP:9000 and IP:8080 NGNIX

Tags: nginx, server, localhost, web-hosting

My ngnix default file have server block like below

```
server {
    listen     80;
    #listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    #listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  myIP;
    root         /var/www/html/web/admin_and_store_panel/; 

    #ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>/fullchain.pem";
    #ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>/privkey.pem";
    #ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    #ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    #ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    #Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
      location = /errorPage.html {
    }

    # force https-redirects
    #if ($scheme = http) {
    #    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    #}
 }
```

it works fine when only one project with ip
like i can access my project with port 8080 with ip

but what i want is to run both project like IP:8080 and IP:9000
can i do that?

Comment: You dont need nginx for this. Simply Start your two services on those ports and they will be available.

Comment: yes exactly, i know that when i do that and try to access in browser it says "This site can’t be reached" so i add this in default file